# Could not update LinearLayout android

Tags: refresh, invalidation

I have a inflated a view in which 4 rows have added, then further four views added in each row. Now I want to update my `LinearLayout` on screen touch ?

Comment: are you working with adapter or simple want to add

Comment: its a simple add to the layout through a for lopp

Comment: You must explain better what you want to achieve. Show us some code, please.